# SSL over FQDN vs IP

Tags: apache, ssl, https, centos

Apache 2.2, CentOS 6, Godaddy SSL (multi domain).

Setting up Godaddy SSL (multi domain) on Apache 2.2 on CentOS, I have a working SSL (https) site but only if I navigate to the server via IP address. If I try to resolve to the domain name (sub.domain.com) I get the following browser msg:

> This webpage is not available 
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have logging set to warn and I have no warnings or errors in the logs for the ssl site.

I am confused and have searched and follow many resolutions for this issue and still cannot get my site to resolve over https using FQDN.

Any directions or suggestions would help greatly. Below is my ssl.conf for Apache:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/webdata/aaa.bbb.COM"
ServerName register.g1e.com:443

ErrorLog /var/www/webdata/aaa.bbb.COM/logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog /var/www/webdata/aaa.bbb.COM/logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/aaa.bbb-com.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/aaa.bbb-com.key

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>


SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means the connection didn't go through, that's before SSL or even apache get involved. Are you sure your FQDN resolves to the correct IP? Are you sure apache is listening on the correct port? Are you sure no firewalls are blocking the traffic?

Comment: I am on AWS EC2 and my public IP is 54.173.114.65 but when I trace route the FQDN I get 2 additional IPs. I assume this is due to the load balancer? I also have made sure that the port is open in firewall (I can hit the https from IP and I have apache Listen 443. So my issue is, yes I know for sure that 443 is open on server and Listen on Apache is working by hitting IP address via https but I cannot get https to hit via FQDN

Comment: I have no idea. Are you querying an FQDN you manage or one AWS does? Do those other two IP addresses respond to requests on 443? What does a reverse lookup on your IP return? What about those other two?

Answer (score 0):

Etan,

Thank you for your responses. Here is what I found and by luck and a few conversations with some knowledgeable friends that lead to some thinking.

For Amazon EC2 load balanced servers you are given an IP address for the server. If you also use Route53 You are provided with an Alias A Name stack address. This resolves to 2 new IP addresses that are related to the Alias A Name. This creates and issue because the SSL is Listening on 443 for the Server IP and traffic will come in on the Alias IP(s).

To resolve this I went to my zone for domain in Route53 and set the record for the A Name to the static IP of the server and DID NOT use the Alias for IPV4 A Name.

Funny how a few conversations will drive you to try new things and wham! you figure it out.

Thank you for your replay and consider this post resolved.

I also came across some good news for Multiple SSL on single IP today might help others...

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm

only thing to remember for AWS EC2 servers is to set DNS to static public IP of server and do not use the load balancer stack IP or endpoint alias for DNS records.

Marcus